# Сyclic shift of all array elements

Tags: python

A list of integers is entered from the keyboard. Write a program that will cycle through all the elements of an array one position to the right (the last element is moved to the beginning of the list).
Input data
The first line contains the number of elements in the list. After that, the list elements themselves are entered - one per line.
Output
Output the list resulting from the shift.
Example
Input data
6
8
12
3
4
5
1
Output
1 8 12 3 4 5

I don't understand what's wrong with this code. It works, but the teacher said that the task was not solved correctly.

```
h = []
k = int(input())
for i in range(k):
    o = int(input())
    h.append(o)
h = h[len(h) - 1:] + h[:len(h)-1]
print(h)
```

Comment: You can use negative indexes to indicate last, second last, etc elements, so your assignment would be better written as `h = h[-1:] + h[:-1]`. Other than that, it depends what your teacher was expecting....

Comment: What happened to the `6` in the example output ??

Comment: It looks fine to me. I don't understand the problem. A few things you can do to improve it though: use negative indices like @treuss suggested. You can get rid of the for loop and append by using a list comprehension: `h = [int(input()) for _ in range(k)]`. But I'm not convinced that's actually more readable.

Comment: @treuss The 6 is the number of elements; it is not part of the array. That pattern is often used in code assignments because it makes it easy to read the input correctly.

Comment: Your output is `[1, 8, 12, 3, 4, 5]`, including brackets and commas. That's probably not the intention. You're probably expected to print the numbers without brackets and commas, either with only spaces between them or perhaps even on separate lines (resembling the input).

Comment: All in all, your logic is correct; check with your teacher to find out what exactly is incorrect (possibly the output format as @RoelSchroeven commented)
.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think there is a typo in the example, the `1` is missing. Did you mean:

```
Input   6 8 12 3 4 5 1 
Output  1 6 8 12 3 4 5
```

EDIT: There is no typo here, the 6 represents how many numbers the user will input, and they are typed line by line. So the following doesn't make sense :)

Did you actually try to run your code with the example? Because it doesn't work :)

###### First, line 2:

You cannot convert a string like "6 8 12 3 4 5 1" directly to an integer because the int() function doesn't know how to deal with the spaces.

###### Then, line 3:

`for i in range(k)` doesn't make sense for python, because k is a list.
The range function takes (at least) an integer and returns a "list" with all the numbers between 0 and this number (excluded). With a quick google search you can find some examples like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp).

The correct way to loop over a string, by character would be:

```py
s = "hello"
for letter in s:
    print(s)
```

or

```py
s = "hello"
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i])
```

Both will output:

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

###### Finally, line 4:

You try to convert the character (I assume) to an integer.
But what if the character is a space? (it will crash)
And what about a number like 12? You will then add 1 and 2 but not 12 to your final list.

To summarize, you need a function that **split** the string on spaces. The `split` function does exactly this! It takes a character and splits a string regarding this character, returning a list of substrings.
Again, you can google it to find [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Here is a solution for you problem, I tried to comment it to make it easier to understand:

```py
inp = input("Please enter several numbers: ")  # read the numbers
inp = inp.split(" ")  # split the input on spaces

h = []
for element in inp:
    h.append(int(element))  # Convert each element to int

# rotate the list 
# you don't need the len(h) here, python handles negative indices
rot = h[-1:] + h[:-1]
print(rot)
```

Comment: The question doesn't make it perfectly clear, but the idea is that the input is in lines. The first line contains the number of elements that  follow (6 in this case), then there are 6 lines with one number per line. The notation 6 8 12 3 4 5 1 is misleading: there should really be 7 lines with one number each instead of one line with 7 numbers. Maybe it's a copy-paste error: it looks like all newlines were lost in the question.

Comment: The 1st number (6 here) is the count of elements in the list, so it shouldn't appear in the output; there's no typo in the question.

Comment: Ooooh then what I wrote doesn't make sense for this question :)